# Sort a field of array upon mysql query

Tags: mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a field: userids which contains 19,2,23 for example, which I populate based on user ids added to a room arbitrarily.  I list the corresponding names based on these userids.

Right now I get Richard, Evan, James from this query (19 = Richard, 2 = Evan, 23 = James).

What I would like to do is sort the array (the field) upon query so that it is 2,19,23 and the names are returned Evan, Richard, James.

So a query that looks like this:

```
    SELECT c.*,c.NAME as PAGE, ASORT(c.USERIDS) as USERIDS, p.* 
    FROM TBL_CONTENT c, TBL_PAGE p 
    WHERE c.PAGEID = p.ID AND FIND_IN_SET(?, c.USERIDS)
```

Should look like (help me with this query)?

of course, the ASORT function does not exist - I just include it as an example of what I am trying to do.

Any help here?
Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't put comma-separated lists in table columns in the first place. If you had it in a separate table you could use `GROUP_CONCAT` and its `ORDER BY` option.

Comment: Then why is FIND_IN_SET even a function?

Comment: Because people have beenmaking this mistake for years and MySQL chose to accomodate them.

Comment: But there's a very limited set of things you can do with them, and sorting is not one of them.

Comment: which mysql version are you using ?

Comment: ok, thanks for that. Perhaps I will just live with the default sort - by members of the room in order of joining

Comment: Why not normalize your table? That way you won't constantly run into problems like this.

Comment: well, it's not really a problem, just on my wish list :)

Comment: @nbk - currently 5.7.26

Answer (score 0):

This works with mysql 8

For mysql 5.x , you need much more code to do that

```
SET @a = '19,2,23';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ord ORDER BY ord) 
FROM
(select  CAST(num as UNSIGNED) ord
from (SELECT @a as names) t
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(t.names), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (num varchar(50) path '$')
) j) z1
```

RESULTS in

```
# GROUP_CONCAT(ord ORDER BY ord)
2,19,23
```

For Mysql 5.x You can use a function

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_split_stringnumbers_and_sort`(_text TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SET @text = _text;
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT((name+0) ORDER BY (name +0)) INTO @output
FROM
(
select
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN (SELECT @text as name) t1
  on CHAR_LENGTH(t1.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t1.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
order by  n
) t2;

RETURN @output;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

SO that this query

```
SET @a = '19,2,23';
SELECT fn_split_stringnumbers_and_sort(@a);
```

has the same result

```
# fn_split_stringnumbers_and_sort(@a)
2,19,23
```

**Caution** 
This function only would split 5 comma separated numbers if you have more than that you have to increase table  with more UNION

Comment: Is this doable in 5.7.26?  or is this strictly 8.x?

Comment: no JSON_Table works only in mysql 8 but you can use the new function i programmed, please see the causion that this function only sorts 5 numkbers, if you have more add more unions in the table numbers